# Google sheets script multiple range and multiple conditional

Tags: google-sheets, multiple-columns, multiple-conditions

I have a spreadsheet, in which I need the script to fetch, over two columns, two pieces of information. And when that's true, I add a formula that adds "1 day" into a third column.

I can make the conditionals run individually. But when I put both, they don't work.

```
function fillColADia() {
  var s =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Afazeres');  
  var dataA = s.getRange("H1:H").getValues();
  var dataB = s.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
    for(var i=0; i<dataA.length; i++) {
      for(var j=0; j<dataB.lenght; j++) {
        if (dataB[j][0] == false) {
          if (dataA[i][0] == 'Zenon') {
          s.getRange(i+1,3).setValue("+1");
         }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

And I also don't know how to add the "add 1 day" formula to the end.

Thanks a lot for the help.

[COPY FILE with dummy data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12S-TDeauObIWDlB_QbuEtnzC4ArW6r05RAqLWoZqeSE/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faaala! Something along these lines as food for thought!
...although I'm certain there are more performant ways to accomplish it:

```
function fillColADia() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Page1');
  var data = s.getRange("A1:H").getValues();
  for (var a = 0; a < data.length; a++) {//Percorre cada linha do intervalo
    if (data[a][0] == false && data[a][7] == 'Zenon') {//Aplica critérios
      let date = data[a][2];//Pega a data daquela linha
      date1 = Utilities.formatDate(addDays(new Date(date), 1), Session.getTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy");//Formata o objeto data, usando a função abaixo para incrementar o dia
      date2 = Utilities.formatDate(addDays(new Date(date), 1), Session.getTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mmss");
      s.getRange(a + 1, 3).setValue(date1);//Põe a data de volta
      s.getRange(a + 1, 4).setValue(date2);//Põe a data de volta
    }
  }
}

//GERA DATAS INCREMENTANDO OS DIAS 
function addDays(date, days) {
  var result = new Date(date);
  result.setDate(result.getDate() + days);
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Faalaa! Haha Thank you very much for the reply. It helped give me some ideas about how to better structure the script. However, it still doesn't work. 

Comment: Please share a copy of the file, with dummy data.

Comment: Okay...Done. 

Comment: Atualizei a resposta, com base nos dados da planilha

Comment: Cara... está perfeito. Agora ele está entendendo as duas condições e isso eu não estava conseguindo. O que é ótimo. Agradeço demais. Só está faltando uma única coisa. Ele está retornando a mesma data. Como faço pra ele retornar a data que estava mais "1"? Por exemplo, se estava 10/04/2022, precisa retornar 11/04/2022. Muito Obrigado mesmo.

Comment: Opa! Que bom que deu certo. Mudaria esta linha do que está para ```date = Utilities.formatDate(addDays(new Date(date), 2), Session.getTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy");``` No entanto, creio que a razão de estar dando este resultado do mesmo dia é por causa do fuso horário em que o servidor "está" vs nossa localização.

Comment: Perfeito! Incrível. Muitíssimo Obrigado! E parabéns pela solução. Resolvido. 

Comment: Acabei de achar outro problema. kkkkkkk. Ele muda a data da Coluna C, ótimo. Mas a coluna D continua com a data anterior. E ela tem que mostrar data e hora. Então não adianta eu colocar embaixo "s.getRange(a + 1, 4).setValue(date);". Eu tentei. Rsrs...

Comment: Eu tenho sofrido com a coleta dos requerimentos no meu dia a dia, de forma que quando da programação, saibamos os "alicerces" que precisam ser construídos. Caso  contrário, vamos fazendo arranjos e o código vai ficando feio - cluncky. Resposta atualizada.

Comment: Fantástico! Parabéns. E Obrigado! Problema Resolvido!

Comment: Valeu! eh nóis!